# Bit-wise efficient uniform random number generation

Tags: java, random, entropy

I recall reading about a method for efficiently using random bits in an article on a math-oriented website, but I can't seem to get the right keywords in Google to find it anymore, and it's not in my browser history.

The gist of the problem that was being asked was to take a sequence of random numbers in the domain [`domainStart`, `domainEnd`) and efficiently use the bits of the random number sequence to project uniformly into the range [`rangeStart`, `rangeEnd`).  Both the domain and the range are integers (more correctly, `long`s and not Z). **What's an algorithm to do this?**

<s>Implementation-wise, I have a function with this signature:</s>

```
long doRead(InputStream in, long rangeStart, long rangeEnd);
```

`in` is based on a CSPRNG (fed by a hardware RNG, conditioned through SecureRandom) that I am required to use; the return value must be between `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd`, but the obvious implementation of this is wasteful:

```
long doRead(InputStream in, long rangeStart, long rangeEnd) {
    long retVal = 0;
    long range = rangeEnd - rangeStart;

    // Fill until we get to range
    for (int i = 0; (1 << (8 * i)) < range; i++) {
        int in = 0;
        do {
            in = in.read();
        // but be sure we don't exceed range
        } while(retVal + (in << (8 * i)) >= range);
        retVal += in << (8 * i);
     }

    return retVal + rangeStart;
}
```

I believe this is effectively the same idea as `(rand() * (max - min)) + min`, only we're discarding bits that push us over `max`. Rather than use a modulo operator which may incorrectly bias the results to the lower values, we discard those bits and try again.  Since hitting the CSPRNG may trigger re-seeding (which can block the InputStream), I'd like to avoid wasting random bits.  Henry points out that this code biases against 0 and 257; Banthar demonstrates it in an example.

First edit: Henry reminded me that summation invokes the Central Limit Theorem.  I've fixed the code above to get around that problem.

Second edit: Mechanical snail suggested that I look at the source for Random.nextInt().  After reading it for a while, I realized that this problem is similar to the base conversion problem.  See answer below.

Comment: Your "obvious implementation" is not only wasteful but also conceptually wrong (apart from a few implementation mistakes). By adding random numbers you change the distribution. If there are enough numbers added it will become gaussian. For example, throwing two dice will produce 7 much more often than 2.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew I did something awfully wrong algorithmically. :S  I should probably get some sleep.

Comment: Look at the implementation of `java.util.Random.nextInt`.

Comment: @Henry, user314104 is not really adding random numbers. He is just concatenating bytes to form a bigger number. This shouldn't introduce any bias.

Comment: @Banthar the question has been edited in the meantime ;-) It's OK now.

Comment: There is still a small bias due to the way the last byte is selected.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm produces biased results. Let's assume `rangeStart=0` and `rangeEnd=257`. If first byte is greater than `0`, that will be the result. If it's `0`, the result will be either `0` or `256` with `50/50` probability. So `0` and `256` are twice less likely to be chosen than any other number.

I did a simple [test](https://gist.github.com/banthar/6657894) to confirm this:

```
p(0)=0.001945
p(1)=0.003827
p(2)=0.003818
...
p(254)=0.003941
p(255)=0.003817
p(256)=0.001955
```

I think you need to do the same as `java.util.Random.nextInt` and discard the whole number, instead just the last byte.

Comment: Correct, to reduce the cases where we overshoot the range, just the necessary bits instead of a full byte could be taken. For example to get a number in [0..700) just take 10 bits instead of two bytes and discard if >= 700.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source to Random.nextInt(), I realized that this problem is similar to the base conversion problem.

Rather than converting a single symbol at a time, it would be more effective to convert blocks of input symbol at a time through an accumulator "buffer" which is large enough to represent at least one symbol in the domain and in the range.  The new code looks like this:

```
public int[] fromStream(InputStream input, int length, int rangeLow, int rangeHigh) throws IOException {
    int[] outputBuffer = new int[length];
    // buffer is initially 0, so there is only 1 possible state it can be in
    int numStates = 1;
    long buffer = 0;
    int alphaLength = rangeLow - rangeHigh;
    // Fill outputBuffer from 0 to length
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Until buffer has sufficient data filled in from input to emit one symbol in the output alphabet, fill buffer.
        fill:
        while(numStates < alphaLength) {
            // Shift buffer by 8 (*256) to mix in new data (of 8 bits)
            buffer = buffer << 8 | input.read();
            // Multiply by 256, as that's the number of states that we have possibly introduced
            numStates = numStates << 8;
        }
        // spits out least significant symbol in alphaLength
        outputBuffer[i] = (int) (rangeLow + (buffer % alphaLength));
        // We have consumed the least significant portion of the input.
        buffer = buffer / alphaLength;
        // Track the number of states we've introduced into buffer
        numStates = numStates / alphaLength;
    }
    return outputBuffer;
}
```

There is a fundamental difference between converting numbers between bases and this problem, however; in order to convert between bases, I think one needs to have enough information about the number to perform the calculation - successive divisions by the target base result in remainders which are used to construct the digits in the target alphabet.  In this problem, I don't really need to know all that information, as long as I'm not biasing the data, which means I can do what I did in the loop labeled "fill."

Comment: I'm starting to realize that there are some conditions which make this problem unsolvable.  I'll edit this answer later to note that.